# How to display percentage with 2 decimals in PieChart?

Tags: jasper-reports, pie-chart

I use Jasper Report 5.2 and I want generate PieChart and display percentage with 2 decimals.

I create the jrxml with one piechart and the datasource is filled with parameter piechart type List.

**The jrxml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Actions" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="70dacc07-184f-471e-ba3c-bd39e77f432b">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="com.gsc.audit.core.actionplan.Action"/>
    <import value="com.gsc.audit.util.Triple"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#EFF7FF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="pieDataset" >
        <parameter name="close_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="late_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="open_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="third" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="second" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="first" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="tableDataset" >
        <parameter name="create_date_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="action_plan_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="state_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="problem_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="first" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="second" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="third" class="com.gsc.audit.core.actionplan.Action"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="now" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="user" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="images_dir" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="report_title" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="footer_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="platform_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="platform" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="pole" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="pole_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="create_date_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="start_date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="end_date" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="to_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="piechart" class="java.util.List"/>
    <parameter name="table" class="java.util.List"/>
    <parameter name="action_plan_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="state_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="problem_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="filter_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="open_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="late_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="close_label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RealSize">
                <reportElement  mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{images_dir} + "rigor.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image scaleImage="RealSize">
                <reportElement  x="457" y="0" width="98" height="30"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{images_dir} + "logo_pgo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <rectangle radius="0">
                <reportElement  x="0" y="20" width="555" height="30" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#999999"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement  x="142" y="34" width="135" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pole}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement  x="142" y="22" width="135" height="12" forecolor="#666666"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pole_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{report_title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement  x="2" y="34" width="135" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{platform}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement  x="2" y="22" width="135" height="12" forecolor="#666666"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{platform_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement  x="283" y="22" width="270" height="12" forecolor="#666666"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{create_date_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement  x="283" y="34" width="100" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{start_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement  x="453" y="34" width="100" height="12"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{end_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement  x="383" y="34" width="70" height="12" forecolor="#666666"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{to_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="280">
            <pie3DChart>
                <chart>
                    <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="555" height="200"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <pieDataset maxCount="3">
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="pieDataset" >
                            <datasetParameter name="close_label">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{close_label}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="late_label">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{late_label}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="open_label">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{open_label}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{piechart})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <pieSeries>
                        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$P{late_label}]]></keyExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{first}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[$P{late_label}]]></labelExpression>
                    </pieSeries>
                    <pieSeries>
                        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$P{open_label}]]></keyExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{second}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[$P{open_label}]]></labelExpression>
                    </pieSeries>
                    <pieSeries>
                        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$P{close_label}]]></keyExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{third}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[$P{close_label}]]></labelExpression>
                    </pieSeries>
                </pieDataset>
                <pie3DPlot legendLabelFormat="{1} ({2})">
                    <plot>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#FA0526"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#1105FA"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#0BDB0B"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel/>
                </pie3DPlot>
            </pie3DChart>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement  key="table" style="table" x="0" y="211" width="551" height="60"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" >
                        <datasetParameter name="create_date_label">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{create_date_label}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="action_plan_label">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{action_plan_label}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="state_label">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{state_label}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="problem_label">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{problem_label}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{table})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="120" >
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="40" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{action_plan_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{first}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="120" >
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="40" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{state_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{second}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="120" >
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="40" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{create_date_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField pattern="yyyy/MM/dd">
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[((Action)$F{third}).getDtActionCreated()]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="190" >
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="40" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="190" height="40"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{problem_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="190" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Arial Black" size="7"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[((Action)$F{third}).getIdentifiedProblem()]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement  x="462" y="0" width="80" height="10" forecolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + "("]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement  x="542" y="0" width="13" height="10" forecolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + ")"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement  x="0" y="11" width="555" height="10" forecolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{footer_label}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement  x="202" y="0" width="158" height="10" forecolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{now}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement  x="0" y="0" width="170" height="10" forecolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="7"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{user}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

With this code the percentage is displayed with one Integer. I want percentage with two decimals. Is this possible?

Comment: yes . with my code the percentage displayed is one integer . i want percentage with two decimals... it is possible?

Comment: Ok, posted answer on how you can use chart customizer, sorry for first version of answer, I was to quick reading your question : )

Comment: Thanks . your solution works perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possibile if you pass a [JRChartCustomizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html)

Example of customizer formatting label as you like

```
public class MyChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart jfchart, JRChart jrchart) {
        PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) jfchart.getPlot();
        StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator labelGen = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator(
                 "{1} ({2})",
                 new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"),
                 new DecimalFormat("0.00%"));
        plot.setLabelGenerator(labelGen);
    }
}
```

In jrxml set the `customizerClass` attribute on chart

```
<chart customizerClass="my.package.MyChartCustomizer">
```

> In IDE you find it in properties: "Customizer Class"

**Note**: the class `MyChartCustomizer` needs to be in classpath when report is executed

**Example output**

[image: Result]